# Run CAML Query on DataTable SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, datatable, caml

I have a DataTable having Some rows. Is there any way to execute CAML Query on it.

Or Alternatively, How can I convert this DataTable into a SPList so tha CAML can be executed on SPList.

```
private DataTable Process(DataTable d, string s)
    {
        DataTable dd = d;
        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
        query.Query = s;
        query.ViewAttributes = "Scope = 'RecursiveAll'";
        DataTable dtSearch = new DataTable();
        SPList Dest = new SPList();


        dtSearch = d.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
        return dtSearch;
    }
```

In above Code d.GetItems can not be done. ???

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried to search data table using api supported by datatable.
For example below msdn article explains Searching row by primary key and searching rows by column values.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this from technet.

```
private SPList dtConvertSPList(DataTable dt)
    {
        SPList newList = null;
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointvm"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {



                    Guid newListGuid = web.Lists.Add("TempList", "This is my temp list, it will be removed when used", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                    newList = web.Lists[newListGuid];

                    if (newList != null)
                    {
                        /* Loop through the datatable and add columns to the list */
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            newList.Fields.Add(dc.ColumnName, SPFieldType.Text, false);
                        }

                        /* Update the list to get the new fields */
                        newList.Update();


                        /* Populate the list from the datatable */
                        SPListItem newItem = null;
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            /* Create a new item in the list */
                            newItem = newList.Items.Add();
                            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                                newItem.Update();

                            }


                        }
                    }
               }
        }
        return newList;

    }
```

But the problem being faced by me is: the outer for loop i.e.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            /* Create a new item in the list */
                            newItem = newList.Items.Add();
                            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                                newItem.Update();

                            }

                        }
```

this outer loop is executing only once out of surprise.

*Debug Findings:
The DataTable passed to  this function had 3358 records.
newList is created Fine with all columns but only one row that too with incomplete information in its columns.

## Improvement Needed:

The loop should work fine and where should i put the code to delete this newList after returnig it?